# Is it possible to replace parentheses with $?

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n = go n []
    where go num acc
            | num < 10 = num : acc
            | otherwise = go (div num 10) (mod num 10 : acc)
```

Is it possible to replace the parentheses in the `otherwise` expression with `$`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The problem

You can't use `$` for that. The purpose of `$` is to make function application bind as un-tighly as possible, as opposed to normal function application which binds most tightly,

```
> :i $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
infixr 0 $
```

(some irrelevant stuff removed...)

Here, `infixr` denotes that the operator is **r**ight associative, as opposed to `infixl` which denotes that the operator is **l**eft associative. `0` denotes the precedence of the operator. `0` binds least tightly and `9` binds most tightly.

If we write `go $ div num 10 $ mod num 10 : acc`, this is interpreted as `go (div num 10 (mod num 10 : acc))`, i.e: passing `mod num 10 : acc` as the third argument of `div`, and the result of applying `div` as the only argument to `go`.

### Solution: the `(&)` operator

Instead of using the dollar sign, `$`, for the left hand side, you can instead use `&`.

```
> :i &
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b       -- Defined in `Data.Function'
infixl 1 &
```

And now we get:

```
import Data.Function ((&))

digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n = go n []
    where go num acc
            | num < 10 = num : acc
            | otherwise = div num 10 & go $ mod num 10 : acc
```

### Solution: apply `go` infix

You could also use `go` infix:

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n = go n []
    where go num acc
            | num < 10 = num : acc
            | otherwise = div num 10 `go` (mod num 10 : acc)
```

In this case, the parenthesis on the right hand side is needed due to `(:)` which is also infix and interferes with `go`.

## Which solution to use

In my opinion, if you can use infix application without parenthesizes, do that. In the case of having a parenthesis on any side such as in: `` div num 10 `go` (mod num 10 : acc) ``, it may still be warranted to use infix. This is mainly due to readability, as the average reader may not be familiar with `&`. This notation is *(probably)* not very commonly used, which is why the average reader is not very familiar with it (and so we have a cycle...).

#### On the usage of `$$`

I believe Alexey Romanov's operator, `$$` is quite neat as well. Unfortunately, it suffers the same problems as `&` does: lack of familiarity. Hopefully, his operator can be added to `Data.Function` in due time and perhaps we can expand our toolbox.

Comment: Note that this algorithm just asks for `divMod` either way, e.g. `go num = case divMod num 10 of (0,r) -> [r]; (q,r) -> r : go q`.

Comment: Valid point, however, it involves a semantic analysis of the algorithm, rather than the broader, and purely syntactic, which the answers discuss. =)

Comment: It's just meant as an additional note, not as a critique of your answer :)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answers @Centril mentions, you can replace only the second pair:

```
go (div num 10) $ mod num 10 : acc
```

or both, but then you need parentheses in a different place:

```
(go $ div num 10) $ mod num 10 : acc
```

or declare another operator like `$` but left-associative:

```
f $$ x = f x
infixl 0 $$

go $$ div num 10 $$ mod num 10 : acc
```

Comment: That operator `$$` is arguably even neater than `&`, nice one =)